# Same exact method used in multiple classes: Logged in functionality

Tags: java, android, methods

I have an android project where I incorporate a login page, and then in each of the activities it checks to make sure they are logged in by checking the shared preferences. I have this in one activity class, but I know I will have to 5 or more times so I am looking into suggestions to not have so much duplicate code.

```
private void findOutMemberAccessLevel(boolean loggedIn) {
    if (loggedIn){
        mViewModel.getmAllMembers().observe(this, new Observer<List<MemberInfo>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<MemberInfo> memberInfos) {
                for (MemberInfo memberInfo : memberInfos){
                    if (Objects.equals(memberInfo.getMemberName(), loggedInName)) {
                        MEMBERACCESSLEVEL = memberInfo.getMemberAccessLevel();
                        break;
                    } else {
                        MEMBERACCESSLEVEL =0 ;
                    }

                }
            }
        });
    }

}

private boolean findOutLogOn() {
    SharedPreferences prefs =
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

    isLoggedIn = prefs.getBoolean("login_check", false);
    loggedInName = prefs.getString("member_name", "NotFilled");
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right way to check if a user is logged in or not. Once the user is logged in, save the login details such as email and password in shared preferences. 
Close the Login Activity so that it can't be accessed again by calling finish() method just below the intent. This way the user can't navigate back to the previous activity.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this,"your targetActivity");
 startActivity(intent);
 finish();
```

On your launcher activty, you should check whether the user details exist in the shared preferences or not. If it exists navigate to the home activity skipping the login activity, else navigate to the login activity.

You don't have to explicitly check each time you navigate to a new activity after this.
Hope this helps.